# Why does gen_server get timeout

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I am trying to figure out why my `gen_server` crashes with a timeout since i am treating all possible cases:

```
module(wk).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).


-record(state,{
    limit,
    count=0,
    toSend
}).
start_link(ToSend,Limit)->
   gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, {ToSend,Limit}, []).



init({ToSend,Limit})->
    State=#state{toSend=ToSend,limit=Limit},
    {ok,State}.


handle_call({process,Message},From,State)->
    {reply,{processed,os:timestamp()},State};
handle_call(Message,From,State)->
    self() ! {from_call,Message},
    {noreply,State}.
handle_cast(Message,State=#state{count=C})->
    self() ! {from_cast,Message},
    {noreply,State}.

handle_info(Message,State=#state{count=C,limit=L,toSend=T})->
    io:format("inside handle_info"),
    T! {badrequest,Message},
    Ret=if C>L -> {stop,State};
           _ ->{noreply,State#state{count=C+1}}
        end,
    Ret.
```

As you can see this server can handles a number of `limit` unknown messages , and as well as `cast` messages.
Now my problem is with the `handle_call`:

- If i send a message that fits the first case  its ok and it replies back
- When i send an unknown message using `gen_server:call(S,xx)` for example, i get a timeout error :

  exception exit: {timeout,{gen_server,call,[<0.102.0>,33]}} in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 215)

Why is my server timing out ? I can see that after `handle_call` it enters into `handle_info` but why does it crash ?

Usage:

```
{ok,Y}=wk:start_link(self(),3).
 gen_server:cast(Y,some_message).  % works limit times and then crashes as expected
 Y ! some_message % works limit times and then crashes as expected
 gen_server:call(Y,some_message) % gets inside handle_info , since i get the io message, then times out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my server timing out ?

From the [gen_server:call()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-2) docs:

> ```
> call(ServerRef, Request) -> Reply
> call(ServerRef, Request, Timeout) -> Reply
> ```
>
> Makes a ***synchronous call*** to the ServerRef of the gen_server process by
>   sending a request and **waiting until a reply arrives or a time-out
>   occurs.**
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Timeout is an integer greater than zero that specifies how many
>   milliseconds to wait for a reply, or the atom infinity to wait
>   indefinitely. Defaults to 5000. **If no reply is received within the
>   specified time, the function call fails.**

Because you chose to return `{noreply...}` in your `handle_call()` function, `gen_server:call()` cannot return and times out after 5 seconds.  You need to manually call `gen_server:reply/2` (in another process) to send a reply back to the client before the timeout.

Comment: Oh so basically it's not the `gen_server` that times out its the caller that does.If this is true why does the server not accept further messages after this one ? Why i can't issue other calls to the server ?

Comment: You called `start_link()` to start the gen_server.  The name "start_link" means: start the server process and link it to the process that called `start_link()`.  And, when two processes are linked, if one of the processes dies the other one is killed.  If you are executing your function calls in the shell, you can call `self().` as soon as you launch the shell to see the pid of the shell process, then you execute `Y.`, after Y is pattern matched to see the pid of the gen_server process....

Comment: ....then after the timeout error, issue the command `i().` and you will see that neither of the two processes exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A few things going on here.

You are sending messages to self() from within the GenServer, which will be sent to the GenServer. Those messages need to be handled in the handle_info block, which I don't see implemented, so at this point, everything is being treated as a bad request.

Second, you are sending messages back to the caller/caster via it's Pid/Name that you hold in state, which is fine for async ops as long as you reply to the calls with something like {reply, "processing call", State}, since you used noreply your calls are timing out as it has been stated already. Usually, you wouldn't want to use a call that returns something right away, but if you need confirmation that the process got the job and is working on it it can be a good handoff of responsibility mechanism. Otherwise, if it's meant to be a syncronious call use the gen_server:reply instead of T ! Message syntax, but you'll have to treat calls and casts differently.

Good luck

Comment: *handle_info block, which I don't see implemented,*  -- Go to the last line of the code and read upwards.

Comment: I see handle_info but not for the specific messages you're sending, unless you want to treat everything the same way, as an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's the client that timeout. once it makes a call to the second clause of gen_server:call/2 the client is still waiting for a response, which never being sent back.